# Python unpickling error this line "data_inputs = pickle.load(f)" throws _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'n'."

Tags: python, pickle

> fileName = myfile.data

### /*datas in the file*/

name,MDVP:Fo(Hz),MDVP:Fhi(Hz),MDVP:Flo(Hz),MDVP:Jitter(%),MDVP:Jitter(Abs),MDVP:RAP,MDVP:PPQ,Jitter:DDP,MDVP:Shimmer,MDVP:Shimmer(dB),Shimmer:APQ3,Shimmer:APQ5,MDVP:APQ,Shimmer:DDA,NHR,HNR,status,RPDE,DFA,spread1,spread2,D2,PPE
phon_R01_S01_1,119.99200,157.30200,74.99700,0.00784,0.00007,0.00370,0.00554,0.01109,0.04374,0.42600,0.02182,0.03130,0.02971,0.06545,0.02211,21.03300,1,0.414783,0.815285,-4.813031,0.266482,2.301442,0.284654
phon_R01_S01_2,122.40000,148.65000,113.81900,0.00968,0.00008,0.00465,0.00696,0.01394,0.06134,0.62600,0.03134,0.04518,0.04368,0.09403,0.01929,19.08500,1,0.458359,0.819521,-4.075192,0.335590,2.486855,0.368674
phon_R01_S01_3,116.68200,131.11100,111.55500,0.01050,0.00009,0.00544,0.00781,0.01633,0.05233,0.48200,0.02757,0.03858,0.03590,0.08270,0.01309,20.65100,1,0.429895,0.825288,-4.443179,0.311173,2.342259,0.332634
phon_R01_S01_4,116.67600,137.87100,111.36600,0.00997,0.00009,0.00502,0.00698,0.01505,0.05492,0.51700,0.02924,0.04005,0.03772,0.08771,0.01353,20.64400,1,0.434969,0.819235,-4.117501,0.334147,2.405554,0.368975
phon_R01_S01_5,116.01400,141.78100,110.65500,0.01284,0.00011,0.00655,0.00908,0.01966,0.06425,0.58400,0.03490,0.04825,0.04465,0.10470,0.01767,19.64900,1,0.417356,0.823484,-3.747787,0.234513,2.332180,0.410335
phon_R01_S01_6,120.55200,131.16200,113.78700,0.00968,0.00008,0.00463,0.00750,0.01388,0.04701,0.45600,0.02328,0.03526,0.03243,0.06985,0.01222,21.37800,1,0.415564,0.825069,-4.242867,0.299111,2.187560,0.357775

---

/* The Following is the Code*/
`f = open("myfile.data", "rb")`
`data_inputs = pickle.load(f)`
`f.close()`

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> line 34, >in 
> data_inputs = pickle.load(f)
> _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'n'.

Comment: The error you're showing isn't even corresponding to any lines you've posted.  Please post the relevant code and actual traceback in your post.

Answer (score 1):

Can you kindly show the data you are loading? Meanwhile try this.

```
with open('myfile.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    data_inputs = pickle.load(f)
```

Comment: Still it gives the same error, the file is myfile.data it contains lists of data